# React native paper Delayed loading of label in textinput when screen having full of textinputs

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

React native paper label rendering slowly when screen having full of textinputs,

I researched about this issue I don't get any feasible solution, Any facing issue like this.....

Issue : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KbP4KgPucbomRQBp6t0yXLrIXaUJA8z5/view?usp=drive_link

**My packages version,**

**"react-native": "0.72.5",**

**"react-native-paper": "^5.10.6",**

Please help me guys,
is there any way to fix this issue?...

Thanks in advance